Odoo tests with forms: AssertionError: field_name was not found in the view
When making tests for a form in Odoo, when assigning a value to a field let say field_name,
my_form = Form(self.env['my.model'])
my_form.field_name = 'test'

inmmediately throwns error:
AssertionError: field_name was not found in the view

The field is on the view. But it has a modifier:
<field name="field_name" groups="base.group_no_one"/>


I really like your questions topics/contents. But SO is a question and answer site. So please try to write down a question. For example: How to give the test user in test environments the right access groups?

it's an error thrown by Odoo, when you look the error on google it is easy to find on SO

I'm not completely convinced yet, but well you'll get the upvote ;-)

Use self.debug_mode():
with self.debug_mode():
   my_form = Form(self.env['my.model'])
   my_form.field_name = 'test'


Could you extend your code example with the usage of self.debug_mode(). Right now the answer could be hard to understand for some people.

thanks, there was a ghost line of code
